# Inflating layouts. ScrollView scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

Есть форма для создание вопроса для теста. Это `ScrollView`. Внизу формы есть кнопка `Добавить ответ`, которая находится под всеми ответами.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view_question_edit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_edit_question"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_edit_question"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            ...
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/answers_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_add_answer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/action_add_answer"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Добавляю я так:

```
View answer = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())
                                .inflate(R.layout.item_question_answer, answersContainer, false);
```

затем прокручиваю `ScrollView` в самый низ, что бы была видна кнопка добавления ответа.

```
mainScrollView.post(() -> mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, mainScrollView.getBottom()));
```

В портретном режиме я добавляю 5-6 ответов и прокрутка `ScrollView` перестаёт работать как нужно. После прокрутки видно половина кнопки Добавить ответ, а затем вовсе не видно. В ландшафтном и вовсе сразу начинает некорректно работать прокрутка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Соглассно [выдаче](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8015313/3212712) гугла на сей запрос:

> [scroll scrollview programmatically android to bottom](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=scroll%20scrollview%20programmatically%20android%20to%20bottom)

Можно ещё такие варианты попробовать:

1. Промотать методом `fullScroll` с параметром `ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN`

   ```
   scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
       }
   });
   ```
2. Вместо прокрутки переместить фокус на последний элемент `ScrollView`, задав ему `true` в качестве значений аттрибутов `android:focusable` и `android:focusableInTouchMode`

   ```
   Button b = ...;
   b.setFocusable(true);
   b.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
   b.requestFocus();
   ```

Comment: Первый вариант сработал) Вроде уже и его пробовал, но что-то тогда не получалось. Спасибо)

Comment: @itslayo, то, что с первого раза не выходит - это нормально) Вот если с первого раза код компилируется, да ещё и не падает во время выполнения - вот тогда надо насторожиться)